# Aura iteration over array of objects accessing key values

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, aura-attribute

I am using aura:iteration to iterate and show images on my lightning component. Which looks like below:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.Assets}" var="asset">
  <img src="{!asset.asset-url}"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

For some reason, the aura expressions can't evaluate **asset-url** and return NaN. Am I doing something wrong here? It works if I do **asset_url**

Comment: does all the elements in list has asset-url populated ? This looks like a data issue

Comment: Yeah, it does. Conventionally, I believe it should be asset_url. I was hoping aura could do something like {!asset['asset-url'}

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to rename your asset-url var - I read somewhere that `-` chars aren't allowed in this syntax... can't remember where though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hyphens are not allowed when declaring a variablle. I suggest you to rename the variable with underscore.